# How to get content of email like as Email ID ,Subject ,Message body text,and Attachment in android?

Tags: android, email-client, email-notifications

I am new to android. I configured the email address in the android emulator.I want to get the email content,if the configured email receives the mail from other mailid.which notification shall i use and how to get the email content when the notification raises the alert. how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to say that you signed-in to the mail app on the Android device. From my understanding of the question you've raise, signing-in to an email account on the Android device doesn't mean any application can just grab emails from it. The closest solution I can think of is creating an IMAP connection to a mail server to grab mail content.