# How to get Email body in android

Tags: android, email, notifications

I am developing an application wherein when an email arrives on our mobile, the application should be able to fetch the body of that email, its sender and so on.

I have surfed a lot but was in vain..

I am new to android..

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110190/how-to-get-content-of-email-like-as-email-id-subject-message-body-text-and-att